# How does headers argument works for RequestMapping annotation?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, header

When I write inside controller method:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=mockDump.csv");
```

It works good.

But when I adds in `@RequestMapping` argument `headers = {"Content-Disposition=attachment", "filename=mockDump.csv"}`

method doesn't invoke.

Why?

Comment: `headers` doesn't add headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @RequestMapping header describes headers which must be present on the request for it to be routed to the annotated method for handling. Where as calling setHeader on a response object sets a header to be sent to the client in the repsonse

Comment: Is it possible to configure sent headers through annotation ?

Comment: You can through the produces and consumes properties in @RequestMapping but I think that is only for the content-type header

Answer (score 1):

As the [`@RequestMapping#headers` javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#headers--) states

> The headers of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.

In other words, `headers` applies to the request headers, helping to determine the appropriate handler method.

If you want the Spring way of adding response headers, ie. not through the `HttpServletResponse`, return a `ResponseEntity` with an appropriate `HttpHeaders` set.